# 'Plonis' in Poskim on Nedarim 20

Tags: marriage, women, sexuality, shevatim-12-tribes, tractate-nedarim

This page on Nedarim 20 is discussing the stringency of a husband avoiding thinking of other women during sex.
https://dafyomi.co.il/nedarim/halachah/nd-hl-020.htm

When it comes to the Poskim discussing rebellious children being born from improper sex, it refers to Jacob, Leah (the deceptive wedding night) and the birth of Reuben, and quotes Magen Avraham:
"Heaven forbid that one of the Shevatim was a rebel! We must say that the problem is only when he saw Plonis on a bed, and later thought that he was with Plonis. Here, Yakov saw Leah and intended to have Bi'ah with her, just he erred about her name."

From the context, am I right to understand that the mention of 'Plonis' is simply a random woman's name that they are using hypothetically for anyone in this situation?

Comment: Plonis is not really a name at all. It’s more of a placeholder, like writing ‘so-and-so’ or ‘Jane Doe’.

Comment: @JoelK Oh thankyou! I actually know a woman called Plonit, so I didn't realise it could function that way! Plus, the words 'such-and-such' or 'a certain woman' get written enough in Talmud that I would have looked for those phrases as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Plony and Plonit are the Jewish equivalents of John and Jane Doe.'

https://www.becomingjewish.net/blog-into-the-jewish-pool/archives/07-2017

Oops XD